# Can I send signed APK though bluetooth to device to quickly test build

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am creating a Xamarin android application. Most time consuming is build deployment which everyone known. 
I tried to send signed APK via Bluetooth from my development machine to device. It gets successfully deployed, but instantly closes after start.
Have anyone tried this way and is there problem testing in device by copying APK?

Comment: please check the option project properties  linker set to "sdkassembliesonly".note: release mode set

Comment: Bluetooth is much slower than having an actual connected device. You can always connect to a device via `adb connect <ip>`: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html

Secondly if your application crashes immediately after it starts, you should view the `adb logcat` to see what's going on with the installation. I personally keep the `Android Device Monitor` tool open with the `adb logcat` running in a window to see what happens when I install to device.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely send the signed APK file (as produced by the build process) via Bluetooth, email or even USB, but it's not likely to offer an improvement on speed.

I do this sometimes when I work from home, as I can't easily connect a device to my work PC (which I'm accessing over a VPN).

If your application is crashing on load when you do that, you've almost certainly got a bug in the application that is causing it.